# Create whole numbers out of split strings

Tags: r, string, merge, split, numbers

I tried to work with merge:

```
budget = sapply(budget1, function(i) {
    Reduce(merge,budget1)[[i]]
    }
    )
```

and get error  Error in budget1[[i]] : no such index at level 1

The problem is that I cannot find a solution to the following problem, does someone know of a way to deal with this data?

I want to add a column to a data frame, that contains the numbers that are still split in the follow list:

```
> budget1
[[1]]
[1] "4"   "000" "000"

[[2]]
character(0)

[[3]]
character(0)

[[4]]
[1] "30"  "000" "000"

[[5]]
[1] "20"  "000" "000"

[[6]]
character(0)

[[7]]
character(0)

[[8]]
character(0)

[[9]]
[1] "22"  "500" "000"

[[10]]
[1] "0"

[[11]]
[1] "4"   "635" "000"

[[12]]
[1] "12"  "000" "000"

[[13]]
character(0)

[[14]]
[1] "9"   "000" "000"

[[15]]
character(0)

[[16]]
character(0)

[[17]]
[1] "18"   "745"  "17"   "2017"

[[18]]
[1] "0"

[[19]]
[1] "47"  "000" "000"

[[20]]
character(0)
```

Comment: Add reproducible examples, expected output and your code that did not work. Make an effort to explain what and how you want to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Your list
budget1 <- list(c("4", "000", "000"),
                character(0), 
                character(0),
                c("18", "745", "17", "2017"),
                c("0"))


#Create toy dataframe
mydataframe <- data.frame(a = 1:length(budget1))


# Add new column "budget" to our dataframe, containing the elements of budget1 as numeric values 

mydataframe$budget <- as.numeric(lapply(budget1, paste, collapse =""))
```

The result:

```
mydataframe$budget

[1]     4000000          NA          NA
[4] 18745172017           0

class(mydataframe$budget)
[1] "numeric"
```